# A minimal size of a set of tuples for an upper bound of a distance between any pair of elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Let $T_i^n$ denote a particular tuple of $n$ natural numbers (here $i < n!$ and we assume that the tuple contains all elements of the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-2, n-1\}$, i.e. there are no duplicates). For example, $$\begin{array}{l}
T_0^4 = (0,1,2,3),\\
T_1^4 = (0,1,3,2),\\
 \ldots \\
T_{23}^4 = (3,2,1,0).
\end{array}$$

(It does not matter how the tuples are enumerated; the example above implies the lexicographic order.)

Then $S_n$ denotes the set $\{T_0^n, T_1^n, \ldots, T_{n!-2}^n, T_{n!-1}^n\}.$ The cardinality of $S_n$ is equal to $n!$

Assuming that $(x, y)$ are two different elements of a given tuple $T$, let $d(T, x, y)$ denote the number of elements between $x$ and $y$ in $T$. For example, if $T = (3, 0, 1, 4, 2)$, we have $$\begin{array}{l}
d(T, 3, 0) = d(T, 1, 0) = d(T, 2, 4) = d(T, 4, 2) = 0,\\
d(T, 3, 2) = 3.
\end{array}$$

A subset $s$ of $S_n$ is called an “$[n, k]$-set” if and only if for any pair $(x, y)$ of elements of the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-2, n-1\}$ there exists an element $t \in s$ such that $d(t, x, y) \leq k$.

Question: given an arbitrary natural number $n > 2$ and a natural number $k$ such that $0 \leq k \le n - 3$, what is the *minimal* cardinality $M(n,k)$ of an $[n, k]$-set?

Comment: So this is the required number of $(k+1)$-th powers of Hamiltonian paths that cover all edges of a $K_n$.

Comment: The easy case is that for $2k \ge n-2$ two tuples suffice: an arbitrary one, and the same one rotated by half its length.